# Count the amount of entries (type) if there are 3 or more for each account number, don't include the account number if it has another type of entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

Each account number has more than one entry in each of the tables I'm using.
I want to return the number of entries for tracking records (lt.type) on an account if there are 3 or more entries with the lt.type 46. I also don't want to include the account number in the result if the account has an entry of lt.type 36.

```
SELECT a.ACCOUNTNUMBER AS [Account Number]
    , CONCAT(n.FIRST, ' ', n.MIDDLE, ' ', n.LAST) AS [Member Name]
    , l.id AS [Loan ID]
    , COUNT(lt.type) as [Number of Tracking Records]
    , n.EMAIL AS [Email]
    , n.HOMEPHONE AS [Phone Number]
FROM dbo.account a
INNER JOIN dbo.LOAN l
    ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = l.PARENTACCOUNT
INNER JOIN dbo.LOANTRACKING lt
    ON l.PARENTACCOUNT = lt.PARENTACCOUNT
    AND l.ID = lt.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.NAME n 
    ON a.ACCOUNTNUMBER = n.PARENTACCOUNT
WHERE lt.type = 46
    AND l.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 112)
    AND lt.ProcessDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateadd(day,-1, getdate()), 
112)
    AND a.CLOSEDATE IS NULL
    AND lt.EXPIREDATE IS NULL
GROUP BY a.ACCOUNTNUMBER, n.first, n.middle, n.LAST, lt.type, l.id, n.EMAIL, 
n.HOMEPHONE
HAVING COUNT(lt.type) >= 3
ORDER BY a.ACCOUNTNUMBER
```

Right now my query is counting the total number of  entries for the lt.type (tracking records) that the account has. I need to show the the amount entries of the lt.type (tracking records) that the account has for lt.type 46 if the account has 3 or more of the lt.type 46, and not include the account in the result if it has the lt.type of 36.

[Here is some sample data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRM2o.png)

[This is my result now:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFY0x.png)

[This is my desired result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvxWW.png)

[Some more sample data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xqnQ.png)

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a simplified query would be helpful.

Comment: When you have a WHERE condition of lt.type = 46 then records of that do not have a value of 46 will be excluded, including lt.type = 36. What is the purpose of the LEFT JOIN? Without sample data it is difficult to give a better answer.

Comment: I have excluded the left join and added some sample data.

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.